# Find limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that

$$a) \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1^p+2^p+...+n^p}{n^p} - \frac{n}{p+1})=\frac{1}{2},$$

$$b) \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^p+3^p+...+(2n-1)^p}{n^{p+1}}=\frac{2^p}{p+1},$$

where is $p \in \Bbb N $.

Thanks to Stolz–Cesàro theorem in $a)$ I went to $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^p}{(n+1)^p-n^p}$$ which after dividing by $n^p$ goes to

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+\frac{p-1}{n}+\frac{p(p-1)}{2n^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^p}}{\frac{p-1}{n}+\frac{p(p-1)}{2n^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^p}} = \frac{1}{\infty}$$
At the same time $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{p+1}=\infty,$$

so initial limit should be $\frac{1}{\infty}-\infty = ?$

I can't figure out what I'm missing ( $b)$ seems to complicated to me so I didn't even try it).

Comment: You are not new here..you know how it goes..what have you tried?

Comment: Faulhaber${{}}$?

Comment: Actually (b) is simpler than (a)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that the sum of the $p^{th}$ powers of the integers is a polynomial of degree $p+1$ in $n$, let $S(n):=\alpha n^{p+1}+\beta n^p+R(n)$.

Then

$$n^p=S(n)-S(n-1)=\alpha n^{p+1}-\alpha (n-1)^{p+1}+\beta n^p-\beta (n-1)^p+R(n)-R(n-1)\\
=\alpha (p+1)n^p-\alpha \frac{(p+1)p}2n^{p-1}+\beta pn^{p-1}+Q(n)$$ where $Q$ is of degree at most $p-2$.

By identification,

$$\alpha =\frac1{p+1},\\\beta =\frac12$$ (which are the first two Faulhaber coefficients.)

This justifies the $\dfrac12$ in a).

For b), consider 
$$S(2n)-2^pS(n)=\frac{2^{p+1}n^{p+1}-2^pn^{p+1}}{p+1}+Q'(n)=\frac{2^pn^{p+1}}{p+1}+Q'(n)$$ 
to get the sum of the powers of the odd integers.

Comment: Please correct it's not $ \beta pn^{n-1} $ but surely $ \beta pn^{p-1} $ that you meant in second line or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Isham: absolutely, thanks.

Comment: you're welcome..........nice job + 1

Answer (score 5):

**Solution for (b):**

$$\lim_n\frac{1^p+3^p+\cdots +(2n-1)^p}{n^{p+1}}=\lim_n \frac{1^p+2^p+\cdots +(2n)^p}{n^{p+1}}-\lim_n\frac{2^p+4^p+\cdots+(2n)^p}{n^{p+1}}$$

$$=2^{p+1}\lim_n\frac{1^p+2^p+\cdots +n^p}{n^{p+1}}-2^p\lim_n\frac{1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}$$

$$=(2^{p+1}-2^p).\lim_n\frac{1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p}{n^{p+1}}=2^p.\lim_n\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^p$$

$$=2^p.\int_0^1x^p\,dx=\frac{2^p}{p+1}$$

Comment: This answer would be more helpful (and I'd upvote it) if it were more detailed. Do we answer questions to show how smart we are, or do we want to help the OP?

Comment: How do we proceed from here?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Edited..!

Comment: @mechanodroid Please See the edition.!

Comment: Ok, I've promised. Why didn't you follow the original idea, a Riemann sum for $$\int^1_0(2x)^p\,dx?$$

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned with Stolz–Cesàro theorem we will get

$$ b)\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { { x }_{ n+1 }-{ x }_{ n } }{ { y }_{ n+1 }-{ y }_{ n } } =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { 1^{ p }+3^{ p }+...+(2n+1)^{ p }-\left[ 1^{ p }+3^{ p }+...+(2n-1)^{ p } \right]  }{ \left( n+1 \right) ^{ p+1 }-{ n }^{ p+1 } } =\\ =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { { \left( 2n+1 \right)  }^{ p } }{ { \left( p+1 \right) n }^{ p }+...+1 } =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { { \left( 2n \right)  }^{ p }+...+1 }{ { \left( p+1 \right) n }^{ p }+...+1 } =\frac { { 2 }^{ p } }{ p+1 } $$